# metric file not found for script font

Tags: fonts, packages, font-metrics

I'm trying to get a handwritten-looking cursive font working in LaTeX. I found a [list](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/calligraphicalfonts.html) in the TUG font catalogue, and thought [Vereinfachten Ausgangsschrift](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/va/) looked right. However, I can't get even the tiniest document to work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{va}
\begin{document}
Some text. {\va Something in cursive}.
\end{document}
```

MikTex auto-installed the `va` package for me. But when compiling this file, I get the following errors:

```
(C:\Users\Nate Glenn\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\fonts\source\lh\base\lkligtbl.mf)
>> 0.14
>> "input ec"
! I can't find file `ec'.
<scantokens> input ec

<to be read again>
                   ;
use_driver->...#=pt#;pt#:=true_pt#;scantokens(ss);
                                                  pt#:=true_pt#;font_identif...
l.304 use_driver(fonteq)
                        ;
Please type another input file name
! Emergency stop.
<scantokens> input ec

<to be read again>
                   ;
use_driver->...#=pt#;pt#:=true_pt#;scantokens(ss);
                                                  pt#:=true_pt#;font_identif...
l.304 use_driver(fonteq)
                        ;
Transcript written on la14.log.
miktex-maketfm.exe: Windows API error 2: The system cannot find the file specified.
miktex-maketfm.exe: Data: la14.tfm

! Font T1/la/m/n/10=la14 at 7.14279pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found.
<to be read again>
                   relax
l.1 \handWritten{Dr. Haller Xeroxed this 9/8/95}

?
```

I'm not sure what a metric (TFM) file is, nor why it didn't come with the package. Can anyone explain the meaning of this error and show me a minimal working document using this font (the one on the font website had even more errors)?

Answer (score 1):

The font you're trying to use is distributed as a set of METAFONT sources, as shown by the reference to the .mf file. TeX is trying to build them into a usable font, but the sources depend on code in the sources for the `ec` fonts. Adding the `ec` package to your TeX setup should fix the problem.